# Angular search bar (chrome ctrl + f)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am creating a search box in angular to search for matching string in a specific div. I want to implement chrome ctrl + f behaviour when user starts typing in search box(after 3 characters). I want to highlight matching string, get the result length and moving to next/previous match. With a pipe i can archive the highlight but not the other requests. Is there any other way to reach this ?

Comment: What do you mean the other requests. Are you looking how to fetch the CTRL +F, are you looking for the highlighting, are you looking for the pipe?

Comment: Thank you for the response @Stefan. I meant the result number and the next/previous functionallity, i can do the highlighting but its not a great way since you must call the pipe for every child component, and inside this child components i have different bindings. I was looking for another way, maybe using DOM to read the match values